# Is start ^ and end $ required for multiple regex patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

If given `[name=anystring]` or `#anystring` where `anystring` is a string which has already had any whitespace removed, I wish to return `anystring`.

Before attempting both, I successfully performed them individually.

```
$pattern = "/^#(.+)$/";
preg_match($pattern, '#anystring', $matches);
preg_match($pattern, '[name=anystring]', $matches);

$pattern = "/^\\[name=(.+)\\]$/";
preg_match($pattern, '#anystring', $matches);
preg_match($pattern, '[name=anystring]', $matches);
```

And then I tried to combine them.

```
# with start ^ and end $ on both
$pattern = "/^#(.+)$|^\\[name=(.+)\\]$/";
preg_match($pattern, '#anystring', $matches);
preg_match($pattern, '[name=anystring]', $matches);

# without start ^ and end $ on both
$pattern = "/^#(.+)|\\[name=(.+)\\]$/";
preg_match($pattern, '#anystring', $matches);
preg_match($pattern, '[name=anystring]', $matches);
```

While I "kind of" get what I am looking for, the second pattern `[name=(.+)]` returns an array with three elements.

Should I have and end `$` after the first pattern and a start `^` before the second pattern?  Can this result in the second pattern returning an array with three elements?

EDIT.  Show how one version displays more array elements

```
<?php

$pattern = "/^(?:#(.+)|\\[name=(.+)\\])$/s";
preg_match($pattern, '#anystring', $matches);
print_r($matches);
preg_match($pattern, '[name=anystring]', $matches);
print_r($matches);

(
    [0] =&gt; #anystring
    [1] =&gt; anystring
)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; [name=anystring]
    [1] =&gt; 
    [2] =&gt; anystring
)
```

Comment: Oh, I think I see part of the problem.  I should only have one `(....)` I think.

Comment: `.` doesn't match `\n` so, assuming you don't have the `s` (single-line mode) flag turned on, your regex of `.+` will only match a given line. You can prepend `^` to your pattern to force it to start at the beginning of the string each time (otherwise it'll keep trying at every character in a string until it finds a match) but that's up to you

Comment: *-Should I have beginning and ending anchors? +Only if you need your regex matches your entire input string.*

Comment: @revo  Yes I do need so.  Since I have two patterns, do both patterns require this individually?

Comment: No they don't need to. Group them `^(?:#(.+)|\\[name=(.+)\\])$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) where numbering of capturing groups begins from the last ID before the group:

```
^(?|#(.+)|\[name=(.+)])$
  ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JcnyGp/2)

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?|` - start of the branch reset group

  - `#(.+)` - a `#` and then Group 1 capturin 1+ chars, as many as possible
  - `|` - or
  - `\[name=` - a `[name=` substring
  - `(.+)` - Group 1 (again) matching 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `]` - a  `]`
- `)` - end of the branch reset group
- `$`- end of string.

Comment: Ah, both return two element arrays.  I could have always dealt with three, but it was bugging me.  May I ask what the initial `?` is used for?  EDIT.  Never mind.  You just answered!

Comment: @user1032531 It is part of the grouping construct. `(?|...|...|....)` is the construct scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine 2 regexes using a non capturing group:

(?:pattern1|pattern2)

I wrote this regex which will capture on both strings:

`(?:\[\w+=(?<bracketword>\w+)\]|\#(?<word>\w+))`

Your match will either have array key bracketword, or word.
Check it out on the regex101 link below.

https://regex101.com/r/AmgHTS/1/

You can also use start and end string ^ and $ if you like. In my edited regex, my test string is two lines (one for each string), so i had to use the multi line flag too.

https://regex101.com/r/AmgHTS/2/

Comment: Thanks delboy,  In the regex101 link, where is it the multi line flag specified.  When I use your pattern with php, I still get a three element array, so I must not be using this flag correctly.

Comment: my regex uses named capture groups, so it should either be $matches['bracketword'] or $matches['word']

Comment: i take it your string won't be multiline though. if you remove one of the test strings and the multiline flag, it should work

Comment: Ah, those flags were hiding from me!  Turns out PHP doesn't like `g`.  I edited my original post to show how either two or three elements are returned.  While using a label like `word` and `bracketword` is nice, I would like the same word found it can't be done so I would next like to return an array with the same number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

To capture only `anything` with both use `Lookbehind` like this :

```
(?<=#|name=)([^\[#\]]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/AmgHTS/4/

for more check :

https://regex101.com/r/AmgHTS/5

Comment: Works as well.  Why isn't something like `.+` or `\w` required with this solution?

Comment: @user1032531 when you write [^something]+ that means it is (.+) except  something